# Web Audio API Timeshifting? (Preserve Pitch)

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

I'm trying to slow-down some audio while preserving the pitch using the Web Audio API.

Chrome and Safari both support playbackRate for  without changing pitch, but I can't find it for Web Audio API.

Is this not possible? Is there another JS library I can use to add this feature? It's critical for my project.

Comment: 3 years later and I'm having trouble finding much information on this exact issue. Have you found any update here? Did you figure anything out? Any idea if this is on the Web Audio API roadmap?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274895/changing-speed-of-audio-using-the-web-audio-api-without-changing-pitch/

Comment: @BrianFitzGerald Wow it's been 3 years! Unfortunately, I never found any reasonable solutions and this project got sidelined. Next time I dust it off the shelf, I'll reinvestigate and post back if I find anything that works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Speed of Audio Using the Web Audio API Without Changing Pitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274895/changing-speed-of-audio-using-the-web-audio-api-without-changing-pitch)